# How can I append to an array identified by a pointer

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, slice

The following code segfaults- how should this be phrased?

```
package main

func main() {
    var a *[]int
    *a = make([]int, 0)
    *a = append(*a, 1)
}
```

Comment: BTW, there is no explicit array in your code, just slice.

Comment: In short: The value of `a` is `nil`. The default value of all pointers is `nil`. On the second line of function `main`, you are de-refrencing `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Making your pointer example working

After declaration, your pointer variable will be `nil,` so you can't set the pointed value (it doesn't point to anywhere yet).

You have to first allocate memory for the pointed value, e.g. with the builtin [`new()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) function:

```
var a *[]int
a = new([]int)
*a = make([]int, 0)
*a = append(*a, 1)
```

Another option is to use a slice [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), and take its address:

```
var a *[]int
a = &[]int{}
*a = make([]int, 0)
*a = append(*a, 1)
```

Yet another option is to use another variable of slice type `[]int`, and assign its address to `a`:

```
var a *[]int
var b []int
a = &b
*a = make([]int, 0)
*a = append(*a, 1)
```

### Abandoning pointers

But know that using slices requires no pointers. You can just assign the return value of `make()` to a non-pointer slice variable:

```
var a []int
a = make([]int, 0)
a = append(a, 1)
```

Comment: You got me confused. Doesn't `make` allocate the memory and hence assign it to *a? If a is a pointer per declaration, why does a=new([]..) even work if it returns an array not a pointer?

Comment: @andig `make()` allocates a slice, but `a` is a pointer, pointing to nowhere. You can't set anything to the memory poitned by `a`, because it points to nowhere. The problem is not with `make()`, the problem is with you trying to assign a value to "something" apointed by a `nil` pointer.

Comment: Still dazzled. From any other language I'd expect a to point to the result of make when the assignment is done. Instead it seems I need to allocate memory for a and then make overrides the memory in that location?

Comment: @andig, you are not really assigning to `*a`, you are assigning to the memory that `a` points to. The pointer has to be initialized before it can be dereferenced.

Comment: @andig You souldn't even use pointers in this case in the first place. I just made your initial code working. You should just assign the return value of `make()` to a non-pointer value.

Comment: Understood. The "assigning to the memory it points to" still seems totally weird. If a was initialized and I assigned a "bigger" array it may not fit into that memory that a points to. Do the semantics change then, i.e. then the a pointer is changed?

Comment: @andig `[]int` is a slice, not an array. These are different things in Go. A slice is just a fixed-sized small header pointing to an actual array. If you don't know the difference, please read this blog post: [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)